# Parsing a HTML webpage in a feature's eventreceiver (Sandbox)

Tags: permissions, sandbox-solution, html

I have set up a feature with an event receiver with the purpose of parsing some values from a website and adding them to a sharepoint list. The parsing code is written with the help of HTML Agility Project which I've deployed to GAC and referenced - the problem however is I now learn that I can't access any external webpages in a sandboxed solution.

`Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.`

How to get around that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry but there is no way a Code in a Sandboxed solution can access anything outside the current site collection. This outside the site collection includes the rest of the internet.

The only solution is if you can deploy a full trust proxy, which isn't possible with Office 365.